# Scripts executed only once, with async bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a modal, like the one below, that load asynchronously its content, with a jQuery *jQuery.ajax()* method.

```
<script>alert('test!')</script>
    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Why when I trigger the first time the modal, **and only** the first time, the alert dialog box appears? If I try again, without reloading the page, I get no more alert dialog box…

## HTML Codes

### Steps attempts

I tried to add some basic [Steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples#basic) inside the async Modal, but it only works the first time… (like any other piece of js code…)

### The javascript code

Here the button that trigger the modal call:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onclick="modalCall('Details')">Details</button>
```

## And the async calls:

### The first attempt, before reading the [doc](https://api.jquery.com/load/#script-execution):

```
function modalCall(url)
{
   $('.modal-content').load(url);
}
```

### The second with $.get… without success

```
$.get( url, function( data ) {
    $('.modal-content').html( data );
    alert( "Load was performed." );
  });
```

Here the **alert( "Load was performed." );** is executed each time I push the button, but not the code inside the modal…

And I get nothing in the console…

Comment: `<script>alert('test!')</script>` will run once the page is loaded. If you want to run it multiple times without refreshing the page, put it in a function and call that function when you want.

Comment: if you want more help, show us how you asynchronously add the modal

Comment: use `shown.bs.modal` event

Comment: @Ayush Gupta `shown.bs.modal` seems to work only at trigger time…

Comment: tracking `shown.bs.modal` behavior shows that it 1) build Steps 2) then wipe out the js code related to Steps…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of debugging, I finally find why…

1. I used templates, and I duplicated `modal-content` class… (one time in the async modal, and one time on the landing page), leading to nested `modal-content`;
2. I used multiple div (each uniquely identified with it's own id) as modal containers (one by async modal, as I saw in some samples), strangely, leading to load one modal in each container… though each pair `data-target`/`#id` was right…

Cleaning all this stuffs solved my problem…